# Problem 01.4.1: Tensor Analysis on Manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis

I just started studying from *Tensor Analysis on Manifolds* by Bishop and Goldberg and I've come across a problem I do not know how to solve.

> Let $f:A\rightarrow B$. Suppose there is $g:B\rightarrow A$ s. th. $f\circ g=i_B.$ Then $f$ is onto, $g$ is $1-1$, $h=f\big|_{gB}$ is $1-1$ onto, and $g=i_{gB}\circ h^{-1}$. Show by an example that f need not be $1-1$.

I do not know how to begin with this problem, despite taking a full page of notes on the previous paragraphs (I've found I retain more if I write it). For instance, the text has said that

> If $C\subset A$, then the *inclusion map* $i_c:C\rightarrow A$ is defined simply by $i_c c=c$,. If $C=A$ then $i_c$ is called the identity map on $C$.

But is this at all useful in the above problem?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions $f : \{0,1\} \to \{1\}$ and $g: \{1\} \to \{0,1\}$ given by $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = 1$, and $g(1) = 0$. Then $f(g(1)) = f(0) = 1$, so $f\circ g = id_{\{1\}}$. However, $f$ is not $1-1$: both $0$ and $1$ map to $1$ under $f$.

Comment: I see... so the very first statement, i.e. Let $f:\left\{0,1\right\}\rightarrow \left\{1\right\}$ is itself keeping $f$ from being $1-1$.

Comment: @jm324354 exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, pick any $b \in B$, and notice that $f(g(b))=b$. Therefore $g(b) \in f^{-1}(\{b\})$. In particular, $f$ is surjective.

If $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$, then $b_1=f(g(b_1))=f(g(b_2))=b_2$, and $g$ is injective. Can you follow a similar approach to complete the exercise?

Comment: I wish I could mark both as right answers!